# How to upload FIT file to Google FIT using its web api?

Tags: node.js, api, google-api, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have a FIT file and want it to upload on Google FIT. I have done the same for Garmin, Strava, and Training Peaks but can't figure out the upload URL for Google FIT.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this.  Google FIT do not understand the .FIT file format. They are not at all related just a coincidence that they both use the name FIT.  The file format was around a long time before Google Fit originally coming from Garmin but now managed by the same team as is responsible for the ANT+ standard.  Your only option is to parse the .fit file yourself using the fit SDK from thisisant.com and then upload the data you recognize that Google Fit understand using the Google apis.  Not an easy task.